# GetImageFieldValue in RenderField pipeline not able to hit

Tags: pipelines

While extending Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetImageFieldValue not getting hit in my code.
Even my component contains media field in it, any specific reason ?

- OR is there any other way to replace run time alt text value in media while using glass mapper to render media field ?
  Html.Glass().RenderImage

below is my code & patch configuration.

Code :

```
public class CustomGetImageFieldValue : GetImageFieldValue
{
protected override void SetRenderFieldResult(RenderFieldResult result, RenderFieldArgs args)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
    if (args.GetField().Value.Contains("{CompanyName}"))
    {
        args.Result.FirstPart =
            result.FirstPart.Replace("{CompanyName}", Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text("CompanyName"));
        args.Result.LastPart =
            result.LastPart.Replace("{CompanyName}", Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text("CompanyName"));
        args.WebEditParameters.AddRange((SafeDictionary<string, string>) args.Parameters);
        args.DisableWebEditContentEditing = true;
        args.DisableWebEditFieldWrapping = true;
        args.WebEditClick = "return Sitecore.WebEdit.editControl($JavascriptParameters, 'webedit:chooseimage')";
    }
}
}
```

patch :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xmlns:env="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/env/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <renderField>
        <processor patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetImageFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="RPM.MarketingSite.Feature.Components.Pipelines.CustomGetImageFieldValue, RPM.MarketingSite.Feature.Components" />
      </renderField>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any issue with your patch file but Your custom processor is missing the `Process(RenderFieldArgs args)` method. You need to update your code a bit. I tested this code with my local and put the breakpoint to validate. it hits the processor code.

```
 public class CustomGetImageFieldValue
    {
        public void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
            if (args.GetField().Value.Contains("{CompanyName}"))
            {
                //Put your custom logic 
                RenderFieldResult result = new RenderFieldResult();
                SetRenderFieldResult(result, args);
            }
        }
        protected virtual void SetRenderFieldResult(RenderFieldResult result, RenderFieldArgs args)
        {
            args.Result.FirstPart = result.FirstPart.Replace("{CompanyName}", Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text("CompanyName"));
            args.Result.LastPart = result.LastPart.Replace("{CompanyName}", Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text("CompanyName"));
            args.WebEditParameters.AddRange((SafeDictionary<string, string>)args.Parameters);
            args.DisableWebEditContentEditing = true;
            args.DisableWebEditFieldWrapping = true;
            args.WebEditClick = "return Sitecore.WebEdit.editControl($JavascriptParameters, 'webedit:chooseimage')";
        }
    }
```

Patch file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="https://www.sitecore.com/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <renderField>
                <processor patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetImageFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="RPM.MarketingSite.Feature.Components.Pipelines.CustomGetImageFieldValue, RPM.MarketingSite.Feature.Components" />
            </renderField>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks your solution works .Not sure, Even inherited GetImageFieldValue wasn't hit that. While added Process method (As you advised) start hitting.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, If this answer or any other one solved your issue, or helps to resolve it, please mark it as accepted for the community. For more details https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: one problem with glass mapper .As i am supposed to replace my custom sting from image  alt text .Below statement gives error if i am inserting alt text string {CompanyName} and using below syntax to render image. (Error: Input string is not correct format- looks like alt text won't accept html characters)
Html.Glass().RenderImage(Model, x => x.BackgroundImage)

Comment: You could ask a new question and share further details there. It would help to maintain the purpose of the platform and also helps avoid confusion for the community.

Answer (score 1):

Change your config a little bit and use the `patch:instead` in place of `patch:after` given like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
   <sitecore>
      <renderField>
         <processor patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetImageFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="RPM.MarketingSite.Feature.Components.Pipelines.CustomGetImageFieldValue, RPM.MarketingSite.Feature.Components" />
      </renderField>
   </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

And check if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks @Sumit Bhatia -problem is to implement Process method (Which i haven't done- As inherited GetImageFieldValue and Overriding SetRenderFieldResult ).Thanks again for Quick reply.

Comment: @Singh Great. Please mark this answer as accepted so it can be helpful to others. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks @Sumit Bhatia, Can't able to accept two answer. yes the one multi list solution was useful, but there can't get accept answer arrow. I marked up arrow here as well as there.
Thanks again for the quick help.